# View with height set to wrap content larger after transition animation

Tags: android, animation, view, transition

So I've got a card view with a constraint layout inside.

Here's a quick mock up of the layout:

- cardview

  - constraint layout
  - text view (visible)
  - text view (gone)
    I've got an even listener on click of the layout that triggers a transition from txt 1 to txt 2 and vice versa.

The transition is quite simple some sliding and fading. The issue is that when logging the measurement of the card height it becomes larger when the return transition occurs.

log output

before transition CardHeight: 321

after transition to txt 2: 512 (which is right since its larger in size)

after transition back to txt 1: CardHeight: 409

Any thoughts on why it makes the view larger on return.

Comment: did you make your text 2 gone ??

Comment: sure did, the first animation set txt 1 to gone and txt 2 to visible and the reverse if clicked again.